# How to iterate through all instances of an entity in Spring data JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity called packet, I want to update an attribute in all instances of that entity. The attribute I want to update is the price of the packet by a given percentage.

This is my entity class, it has both controller and service class:

```
@Entity
public class Packets {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal packetPrice;

...constructors, getters, setters...et
)
```

This is the class which I'm using for the @PutMapping:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "changePrices")
public class ManipulatePrices {

    @Autowired
    PacketService packetService;

    @PutMapping(path = "minus/{percentage}")
    public void discount(@PathVariable("percentage") double percentage){
        percentage = (100 - percentage)/100;
        packetService.discount(percentage);
    }
}
```

and this is the method in the PacketService class:

```
@Service
public class PacketService {

    private final PacketRepository packetRepository;
    
      public void discount(double percentage) {
        for(int i=0; i < packetRepository.count(); i++) {
            Packets packets = packetRepository.findAll().iterator().next();
            BigDecimal finalPrice = packets.getPacketPrice().multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(percentage));
            packets.setPacketPrice(finalPrice);
            packetRepository.save(packets);
        }
    }
```

so what's happening is that the change is being applied only to the first instance of the Packet entity (with id=1). How can I iterate through all the instances?

Comment: `packetRepository.findAll().iterator().next();` every time fetches all entities, gets the iterator, gets the first element out of it and then you process that. Remove the for loop and use the iterator properly. Also the performance of that would be terrible, in production-grade code you would execute a JPQL query or a native SQL query to perform the modification without fetching each entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this method to your repository ,it'll modify all the entries of Packets table :

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(value=" UPDATE Packets p SET p.packetPrice = :percentage/100 ")
//p.packetPrice = :percentage/100 is just for the sake of the example
//keep in mind the :percentage is refering to the method parameter
void discount(@Param("percentage") double percentage);
```

Now you call this method in your modifying method of the RestController

```
@PutMapping(path = "minus/{percentage}")
public void discount(@PathVariable("percentage") double percentage){
    percentage = (100 - percentage)/100;
    packetRepository.discount(percentage);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@Service
public class PacketService {

    private final PacketRepository packetRepository;
    
      public void discount(double percentage) {
        List<Packets> packets = packetRepository.findAll();
        List<Packets> newPackets = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i < packetRepository.size(); i++) {
            Packets packet = packets.get(i);
            BigDecimal finalPrice = packet.getPacketPrice().multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(percentage));
            packet.setPacketPrice(finalPrice);
            newPackets.add(packet);
        }
        packetRepository.save(newPackets);
    }
```

In this way, you get the list using findAll(); and then you iterate over that list. In newPackets variable you are storing your packets with new price. After the loop, you are storing the whole list in your db in a single query. This will help you with performance too.

Comment: This way you'll end up with the OOM error.